# IFS formula with date types as conditions

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, ifs

I have two different date types in my table: the first is simple `YYYY-MM-DD`, the second contains the week number and year.

How is it possible to build an `IFS` formula, where these two date types are conditions? Like:

```
=IFS(A1="YYYY-MM-DD", "A", A1="WWYYYY", "B")
```

Comment: If that are really dates you can't do this with formulas. Any example for us?

Comment: yes, these are real dates:(

Comment: Could you share example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply use following formula:

```
=IFS(LEN(A1)=10,"A",len(A1)=6,"B")
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see Google Sheets Data Format `WWYYYY` then I assumed that you have text values. If it's true then you can try `REGEXMATCH`

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(J8,"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"), "A",REGEXMATCH(J8,"\d{6}"), "B")
```

[image]

But for me I will not save Dates as text. It requires a script

```
/**
*
* @customformula
*/
function PATTERN_EXTRACTOR(pattern, a1Notations) {
  var patt = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(a1Notations);
  return range.getDisplayValues().map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(cell) {
      return cell.replace(patt,'X');
    });
  });
}
```

Getting pattern

```
=PATTERN_EXTRACTOR("\d",CELL("address",I8))
```

[image]

Resolve conditions

```
=IFS(I10="XXXX-XX-XX", "A",I10="XXXXXX", "B")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this could work too:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A1:A5)), "A", 
              IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5),           "B", )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @contributorpw  like you said, there is no official `wwyyyy` format/string pattern